# GCP CloudBuild -> Failed to trigger build: unrecognized arguments

Tags: google-cloud-platform, build, gcloud, google-cloud-build, build-triggers

I want to run a trigger by passing some substitution values by using gcloud command. Here is my command:

gcloud beta builds triggers run my-service --branch=test-deploy-of-history --project=dev-project --substitutions=_SERVICE_NAME=flow

After entering the command, I am getting this error message:

ERROR: (gcloud.beta.builds.triggers.run) unrecognized arguments: --substitutions=_SERVICE_NAME=flow

Is there any way to pass substitutions values while using this command ?

Comment: can you try  updating the beta component with `gcloud components update`.Refer this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/update)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 433.0.0 of the Google Cloud SDK (released on May 31, 2023), there have been some breaking changes to the `gcloud beta builds triggers run` command.Refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#cloud_build_2) for more information

> Cloud Build
>
> - Added flag to specify substitutions in gcloud builds triggers run.
> - Modified `--branch`, `--tag`, `--sha` flags to be optional in `gcloud builds triggers run` command.

You can try updating the beta component; it will  update all of your installed components to the latest version.you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/update)

```
gcloud components update
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked for me now. I tried gcloud components update and it worked for me. I was missing that portion as my local versions were not up to date.